# Remove color representation of legend matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am using python and the matplotlib library to compare two algorithms.

I would like to know how I can remove the color representations of the lines in the legend excluding the GA and PSO which are the curves of my chart.

Is it possible to do this to keep only the text in the legend?

Here is my plot: [image: plot image]

Here is my code:

```
plt.plot(resultGA[0].n_evals, resultGA[0].x_f_vals)
plt.plot(resultPSO[0].n_evals, resultPSO[0].x_f_vals)
plt.plot(0, 0)
plt.plot(0, 0)
plt.plot(0, 0)
plt.plot(0, 0)
plt.plot(0, 0)
plt.plot(0, 0)
plt.xlabel("Número de gerações")
plt.ylabel("Fitness")
plt.title("Gráfico de convergência")

plt.legend(
    [
        "GA",
        "PSO",
        "Melhor valor(GA): " + str(round(minorValueGA, 4)),
        "Melhor valor(PSO): " + str(round(minorValuePSO, 4)),
        "Tempo GA(ms): " + str(round(benchmarkTimeGA, 4)),
        "Tempo PSO(ms): " + str(round(benchmarkTimePSO, 4)),
        "Melhor Fitness(GA): " + str(round(resultGA[1], 4)),
        "Melhor Fitness(PSO): " + str(round(resultPSO[1], 4)),
    ],
    loc="top left",
)

plt.show()
```

Thanks.

Comment: change all `plt.plot(0,0)` to `plt.plot(0,0, 'w-')` to color the lines white to match the background.

Comment: I suggest reading [the legend guide](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html). It'll teach how to create any legend you want.

Comment: @Aaron It worked perfectly, thank you very much!